# Using the same RecyclerView.Adapter with a different ViewHolder

Tags: java, design-patterns, android

I would use the same [`RecyclerView.Adapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html) with two or more different fragments. Every fragment uses a different view items layout so I must use a different [`RecyclerView.ViewHolder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html) for binding the data.

For the implementation I have created one `RecycleView.ViewHolder` that binds the two different view layout with a switch but I think might be something better for this kind of situation.

```
public class TFViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

    public final static int LAYOUT_ONE = 1;
    public final static int LAYOUT_TWO = 2;

    public Integer mId;

    public ImageView mThumb;
    public TextView mName;

    public TextView mTitle;
    public TextView mDescription;

    public final View mView;

    public TFViewHolder(View itemView, int layoutType) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;

        switch (layoutType) {

            case LAYOUT_ONE:
                mThumb = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumb);
                mName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                break;
            case LAYOUT_TWO:
                mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                mDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
                break;
        }

        itemView.setTag(itemView);
    }
}
```

The `RecyclerView.Adapter`:

```
public class TFRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TFViewHolder> {

    protected Context context;
    protected List items;
    private int layout;
    private int layoutType;

    public TFRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public TFRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, int layout, int layoutType) {
        this(context);

        this.layout = layout;
        this.layoutType = layoutType;
    }

    public void setItems(List items){
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final TFViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.mId = position;
    }

    @Override
    public TFViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

        return new TFViewHolder(itemView, layoutType);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int l = 0;

        if (items != null) {
            l = items.size();
        }

        return l;
    }  
}
```

Two different adapters that extend the `TFRecyclerViewAdapter` of above:

```
public class TFNewsRecyclerViewAdapter extends TFRecyclerViewAdapter {

    public TFNewsRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, int layout) {
        super(context, layout, TFViewHolder.LAYOUT_NEWS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TFViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final News item = (News) items.get(position);

        holder.mTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.mDescription.setText(item.getDescription());

        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class TFTeamsRecyclerViewAdapter extends TFRecyclerViewAdapter {

    public TFTeamsRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, int layout) {
        super(context, layout, TFViewHolder.LAYOUT_TEAMS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TFViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Team team = (Team) items.get(position);

        Glide.with(holder.mThumb.getContext())
                .load(team.getThumb())
                .fitCenter()
                .crossFade()
                .into(holder.mThumb);

        holder.mName.setText(team.getName());

        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Commenting because I haven't had time to look too closely, but instead of switching inside the ViewHolder you could create multiple ViewHolder objects and make use of `getItemViewType()` as described on this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type

Comment: what if I want to use same adapter for different fragments?